# Get all cronjobs that are currently running linux

Tags: php, linux, cron, centos7

We're having a lot of cronjobs on our server and looking for a way to manage them.

A lot of functionality is covered but one thing im still working on, is a way to list all the cronjobs that are currently running.

The following does the job kind of:

```
class Cronjob{

static private function stringToArray($jobs = '') {
    $array = explode("\n", trim($jobs)); // trim() gets rid of the last \r\n
    foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
        if ($item == '') {
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $array;
}


static public function getAllJobsRunning(){
    $output = shell_exec("ps -ef | grep apache");
    return self::stringToArray($output);
}
}
```

But this returns more tasks and not only the cronjobs like

```
apache 6018 6015 0 Sep12 ? 00:00:02 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache 6022 6015 0 Sep12 ? 00:00:08 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache 6023 6015 0 Sep12 ? 00:00:07 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache 7022 6015 0 14:14 ? 00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
root 8544 8485 0 14:41 pts/1 00:00:00 su apache
apache 8545 8544 0 14:41 pts/1 00:00:00 bash
apache 8642 8640 0 14:43 ? 00:00:00 /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/php /path_to_file/something.php > /var/log/cronlog/dailylogs.log 2>&1
apache 8643 8642 0 14:43 ? 00:00:04 /usr/bin/php /path_to_file/something.php
apache 11132 15438 0 14:58 ? 00:00:00 sh -c ps -ef | grep apache
apache 11133 11132 0 14:58 ? 00:00:00 ps -ef
apache 11134 11132 0 14:58 ? 00:00:00 grep apache
apache 11454 6015 0 Sep12 ? 00:00:06 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache 15438 6015 0 11:29 ? 00:00:02 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache 17761 6015 0 11:51 ? 00:00:01 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache 18274 6015 0 Sep13 ? 00:00:06 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
root 18911 11790 0 12:04 pts/0 00:00:00 su apache
apache 18912 18911 0 12:04 pts/0 00:00:00 bash
apache 21863 6015 0 12:42 ? 00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache 24419 6015 0 Sep13 ? 00:00:02 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache 24436 6015 0 Sep13 ? 00:00:02 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
```

While im only interested in the:

```
apache 8642 8640 0 14:43 ? 00:00:00 /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/php /path_to_file/something.php > /var/log/cronlog/dailylogs.log 2>&1
apache 8643 8642 0 14:43 ? 00:00:04 /usr/bin/php /path_to_file/something.php
```

Now I could write a regex that filters out the lines I want but Im wondering if there isnt a easier way to do this.

Comment: Would `/path/to/file` contain anything unique to crons? like `/my path/to/crons` ?

Comment: Hmm yeah it does. I could indeed check it with that information, but I am wondering if there isnt a command that just returns the cronjobs. For example I was thinking I could create a seperate user that just runs the cronjobs so that asking for that users tasks will only return cronjobs. But maybe there are other better solutions?

Comment: No, `ps` lists running processes without any indication whether it was started as a daemon, cronjob, or by user. What you can do is to compare a list of defined cron jobs you got from crontabs against running processes. Using a separate user for cron jobs may work, but you will lose flexibility of assigning different permissions to different cronjobs.

Comment: Look here https://serverfault.com/questions/709713/list-all-running-cron-jobs

Comment: @AlexBlex Hmm yeah. Ill go for that I guess. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

You just want the list of sheduled cronjobs or actually the activity?

Use the following commands isntead of `ps -ef | grep apache` if you want to list all shedules.

Get the crontab for all users:

```
for user in $(cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd); do crontab -u $user -l; done
```

Get the crontab for a specific user

```
for user in $(cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd); do echo $user; crontab -u $user -l; done
```

Comment: Actually the activity

Comment: You will have to compare the running tasks with the tasks you pull out of the crontab with the commands I gave. There is no other way to distinguish them.